# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

code on github: https://github.com/Youngv/bbs

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3: <% @posts.each do |post| %>
4:     <div class="post-line">
5:       <div class="title">
6:       <%= link_to post.title, post %>
7:       </div>
8:       <div class="info">
9:         <% if !post.user.blank? %>
```

In the server it shows: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass)`

I don't have the "gsub" in my code, but this problem showed up, how can I change the code?

Comment: Which file and line did the error occur?

Comment: your gsub problem is likely here #app/helpers/nav_link_helper.rb on line 116